# Only display the highest alpha in loop

Tags: sql, max, mariadb

I want to only display the highest value of them all, within a `foreach` loop. The following query is inside this `foreach` loop.

```
SELECT MAX(substring_index(data_column, ' ', -1))
FROM table
WHERE id = '{id-from-the-loop}'
AND data_column != ''
```

The query gives me this result:

```
Data A
Data A
Data C
Data B
Data G
Data E
```

`G` is the highest value in the list above, so it will show like the list below, but I can't figure it out!

```
Data
Data
Data
Data
Data G
Data
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, write a subquery to get highest value of them all by `limit 1` and `order by`

then self `outer join` with `coalesce` function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(col varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data C');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data G');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Data E');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT coalesce(t2.col,substring_index(t1.col, ' ', 1)) col
FROM T t1 LEFT JOIN (
   select col 
   from t
   order by col desc 
   limit 1
) t2 on t1.col =t2.col
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7af8a8/15/0)**:

```
|    col |
|--------|
| Data G |
|   Data |
|   Data |
|   Data |
|   Data |
|   Data |
```

Comment: @Erik No problem glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since MariaDB 10.2.0 you can use the windowed version of `max()`. Check in a `CASE` if the second part of the string is the maximum for an ID and return the full string if it is. Otherwise return only the first part.

```
SELECT CASE substring_index(t1.data_column,
                            ' ',
                            -1)
         WHEN max(substring_index(t1.data_column,
                  ' ',
                  -1)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN
           data_column
         ELSE
           substring_index(t1.data_column,
                          ' ',
                          1)
       END
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE id = ?
             AND data_column <> '';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=42cd8a31cc8158e34f2b0677de29555c)

I don't know what the context is, but if possible you should not use such a loop of the IDs but generate the full set and then iterate over that. That is likely to much faster. Assuming you got a list of IDs you want to process this may use `IN` and look like:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE substring_index(t1.data_column,
                            ' ',
                            -1)
         WHEN max(substring_index(t1.data_column,
                  ' ',
                  -1)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) THEN
           data_column
         ELSE
           substring_index(t1.data_column,
                          ' ',
                          1)
       END data
       FROM elbat t1
            WHERE id IN (?, ..., ?)
                  AND data_column <> '';
```